# How to start a scheduled thread when no much requests coming to the web application?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, concurrency

I have a java web application that's expected to have many users who will make a strong load on it. At the same time, there are some scheduled tasks that require a lot of processing and I was looking for some automated way to start this thread and pause it according to the high load of the web requests. Is there any ready solutions available there for this task?

Answer (score 1):

- Use a `javax.servlet.Filter` with a static counter, incremented and decremented by the filter. This way you know the current load (= number of requests being processed currently)
- Use `@Startup` with `@Singleton` and `@Schedule` to have a regular task (or any other scheduler like Quartz), for example every 5 minutes
- In that task check the load. If it's low, enough start the real task(s).
- You could monitor the current load in *running* tasks as well, and pause or exit, for example.

This works, if the real task is processing the contents of a queue for example.

Otherwise you possibly have to do some book-keeping, if the frequency of the first task is higher than the frequency of the real task or you have to make sure that the real task is only run once per day (or at least once a day).

Example code:

The filter:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoadFilter implements Filter {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoadFilter.class
            .getName());

    private final static AtomicInteger load = new AtomicInteger();

    public static int getLoad() {
        return load.get();
    }

    public void init(final FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
        log.info("Hello from init()");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final int currentLoad = load.incrementAndGet();
        try {
            log.info("Current load (enter): " + currentLoad);
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        } finally {
            final int newLoad = load.decrementAndGet();
            log.info("Current load (exit): " + newLoad);
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Bye from destroy()");
    }
}
```

and the EJB

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupSingleton {
    @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void execute() {
        // Check load; if low, run task(s)
        if (LoadFilter.getLoad() < 10) {
            // Run tasks
        }
    }
}
```